# FBO texture aliased when rendering in immediate mode

Tags: c++, opengl

I am having a strange issue.I render geometry with OpenGL 4.2 programmable API in compatible mode.I render it into MSAA texture in a custom FBO first.Then resolving it into regular texture attachment.I am getting nice and smooth results x4 samples).But I have a debug drawing mode which renders gizmos and bounding box right after the main geometry pass into the same buffer.Once I turn it on I am getting aliased edges for the geometry.I can't figure out why is that? Is it possible that MSAA stops working once I use both fixed and programmable pipeline in a single render pass ?

Here is the result with debug draws off :

[image]

And this one is when debug draws are on:

[image]

Another finding -in such a "combined" mode the hardware alpha blending doesn't work as well.

Comment: Why would you want to use both fixed and programmable pipeline? That's like the worst idea ever.

Comment: You are asking a very specific question.  Try placing a bounty on it and you will get some more eyes.  I personally don't have an answer for you :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan SO AFAIK is the place to ask such questions ;)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz ,that is only in debug mode.I find it very fast to draw gizmos in immediate mode.And though it won't be active in production version I am curious to know why it behaves like this.

Comment: @MichaelIV why are you concerned about lack of AA in Debug mode at all, then? Either ignore that or write a few debug draw utils using programmable pipeline.

Comment: Agreed, just saying that don't be surprised if it takes a couple tries to get something that isn't tagged "C", "C++", or another programming langauge answered.

Comment: Because I debug not only transformations but also the visual effects ,artifacts etc..

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that is probably what I will eventually do,but before that I would like to know why it works like that.

Comment: @MichaelIV That might be a driver gimmick. My bet would be to test on some other hardware.